# how to validate a data transfer from an external database (oracle) to hdfs

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I have a job that transfers data from oracle to hdfs. I need an efficient way to validate this transfer, to make sure that the all the rows are properly transferred.

Comment: Seen this? https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#validation

Comment: yes.. but needs extra implementation to do row wise validation

Answer (score 0):

A simple way I feel is to take the count of rows from Source Oracle table

```
 select count(*) from tablename;
```

You will get the count of rows from the Oracle table

From HDFS point of View

Count total number of lines(rows) in HDFS file:

```
 hadoop fs -cat /yourdestinationhdfsfiles/* | wc -l
```

Data Validation strategy

Create a (Temp) Hive table similar to Oracle table **structure**

Take few records from the Target HDFS file and load the data into HIVE table and validate if records and structure are matching.[Manual process for validation]

Note: This can be done for full data also provided you have enough storage space and processing unit.

**Hope this Helps!!!..**

Comment: Counting rows doesn't ensure that the column is content matches, though

Comment: agree with @cricket_007, need to make sure that the content also matches, so this solution is not optimal